# Include multiple php files in one line for linux cronjob

Tags: php, foreach, cron, include

I have a lot of dynamic images based in php files. When I visit these files, the content (image) is updated.
I use this command lines for visit the php files in the linux cronjob:

```
*/10 * * * * curl -q https://website.com/folder/A1-imageproduct1.php
*/10 * * * * curl -q https://website.com/folder/A1-imageproduct2.php
*/10 * * * * curl -q https://website.com/folder/A1-imageproduct3.php
```

I would like to use a single command line, since it is a very large number of files.
I tried to create a php file with this code:

```php
<?php
        foreach (glob("A1-*.php") as $name)

    {
        include($name);
    }
?>
```

but only includes the first file, the rest are apparently ignored, both visiting the file with linux cronjob and from my web browser.

Comment: Try && operator for multiple

Comment: */10 * * * * curl -q https://website.com/folder/A1-imageproduct1.php && https://website.com/folder/A1-imageproduct2.php && https://website.com/folder/A1-imageproduct3.php

Comment: thanks but I don't want to add new files manually, since many are created daily and it would be a waste of time to add one by one, that's why I want to include all the files in the same folder that start with A1

Comment: Your code works. Check the includes for variables that are set from the previous one. Make sure a loop or if is not preiously set. You have everything running is one instance. With out disciplined coding you could have lots of overlap in you variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to make a call from curl you should do something like that

```
<?php
 $llamar = new class{
   public function curl($file){
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://website.com/folder/".$file);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
     curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch);
   }
 };
 foreach (glob("A1-*.php") as $name){
   $llamar->curl($name);
 } 
?>
```

If you don't recover all the files it would be better to use this class
Change "RUTE" to the path of your directory

```
$llamar = new class{
    public function curl($file){
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://website.com/folder/".$file);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
    }
  };
$archivo = new class{
    public function leer($carpeta)
    {
        $archivos = array();
        if (is_dir($carpeta)) {
            if ($dir = opendir($carpeta)) {
                while (($archivo = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
                    if ($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.htaccess') {
                        if (file_exists($carpeta . '/' . $archivo)) {
                            if (!is_dir($carpeta . '/' . $archivo)) {
                                $archivos[] = $archivo;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                closedir($dir);
            }
        }
        return $archivos;
    }
}


  $archivos = $archivo->leer("RUTE");
  for($i=0;$i<count($archivos);$i++){
    $llamar->curl($archivos[$i]);
  }
```

Comment: thanks, It seems to work, but for some reason, just visit 15 files out of a total of 21.

Comment: thanks but this new class use a .htaccess I am using nginx, not apache, then I imagine it must be adapted for nginx

Comment: Okay, the first code works, I find the problem, if the file name contains a space and the letter h, it does not work, I don't understand why this is due, maybe a php or nginx problem. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think your path incorrect,add relative path

Try it

```
$cwd=getcwd();


foreach (glob("$cwd/folder/A1-*.php") as $name)  {
        include($name);
 }
```